# Coming up with differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponentiation, applications

This isn't for homework or anything - I came across a problem in which you start with one amoeba in a jar and you know that a single amoeba will spawn another one every three minutes. The original questions states that the jar is full after one hour and asks when it was half full. A common sense approach yeilds 57 minutes, but I was wondering how I'd turn this into a differential equation problem if I wanted to solve it that way.

If $A$ is the number of amoebae, and $t$ is the number of minutes that have passed since you start, I'm looking for an expression for $\frac{dA}{dt}$. If you were told that they doubled every minute then I know it'd be $\frac{dA}{dt} = 2A$, but I'm stuck on how to deal with the every three minutes thing.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: the differential equation is $\frac{d A(t)}{d t} = k A(t)$ with $A(0) = 1$ to which the solution is an exponential, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth

Comment: I forgot to edit my comment again, but the constant k is the growth rate per minute here not the one per every three minutes, this is why its left as k until you use given conditions to solve for k in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equation is 
$$
\frac{dA(t)}{dt}=kA(t)
$$
with the initial condition $A(0)=1$. So the solution is
$$A=e^{kt}$$
and, since $A(3)=2$ we have $e^{3k}=2 \Rightarrow k=\dfrac{\log 2}{3}$ and the equation is
$$
A(t)=e^{\frac{\log 2}{3}t}
$$
with the time $t$ measured in minutes.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm interested to know what is wrong.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted it